# Why does setf work in repl but give an error when compiled?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

When I use setf in the repl it works fine, but if I try to use it in a file and then compile it and send it to the repl, it gives an error. Why am I seeing this strange behavior?

Works fine in repl:

```
(setf books 
  '((war-and-peace leo-tolstoy)
(spin charles-wilson)
(harry-potter jk-rowling)
(speaker-for-the-dead orson-scott-card)))
```

Gives this error when compiled from file:

```
clagitsc.lisp:187:1:
warning: 
BOOKS is neither declared nor bound,
it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
warning: 
in #:|187 193 (SETF BOOKS '(# # # ...))-34| in lines 187..193 : BOOKS is neither    
declared nor bound,
it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.

Compilation failed.
```

I'm using slime with emacs 24.3 on windows with CLisp 2.49 and I'm working my way through Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because books is not explicitly declared as a variable. In repl mode your lisp maybe silently assumes it is special but during compilation it throws a warning. You can 'create' global dynamic variable using defvar or defparameter forms. (Read more here: http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_defparametercm_defvar.html).
To create C-like globals (that are just globals i.e. share value between all threads) you should find analog for sb-ext:defglobal in CLisp.

Answer (score 2):

The exact effects of setting an undeclared variable is undefined in Common Lisp. In CLISP you get thus a warning. But a warning is not an error and compilation usually does not fail in CLISP because of that.

Nowadays we write it as

```
(defvar *books* '(...))
```

and use the variable `*books*` to make it clear that it is a variable which is declared special, globally. It prevents *clashes* with lexical variables.